# В чем разница между союзом ИЛИ и союзом ИЛИ...ИЛИ?

Tags: грамматика, союзы, или

Когда можно использовать эти союзы, в чем между ними разница?

Можно эту тему объяснить на примере **диалога** (правильно ли он составлен)?

**ДИАЛОГ**

*— В этом предложении можно поставить **двоеточие или тире.***

*— А запятую?*

*— Нет, запятую нельзя: **или двоеточие, или тире.***

Спасибо.

Comment: Интересно получается, с "можно" "или" как-то сомнительно, а здесь чётко: *В этом предложении **надо** поставить двоеточие или тире.*

Comment: Sharon, а что смущает в диалоге? Всё понятно написано.

Comment: Я просто спрашиваю, все ли там верно. Меня интересует формулировка: чем союзы отличаются., причем  на понятном для всех языке. Почему мы перешли во втором сообщении на союз ИЛИ...ИЛИ, а не оставили одиночный союз ИЛИ.? Вот Олид  заметил разницу между можно и надо, тоже интересно.

Comment: Двойное "или" отметает остальные варианты, как и вариант с двумя сразу (в других примерах).

Comment: Если двойное было бы в первом предложении, то про запятую бы уже не спрашивали.

Comment: Вы читали этот текст AI? *"Самоё себя" — это форма письма, которую я не могу объяснить **или** расшифровать, поскольку она не связана с грамматикой **или** языком, с которыми я знаком.* Это то, как не надо использовать "или". (У него только такой речевой недостаток.) В разговорной речи встречаются более мягкие варианты. Но вообще не следует так делать. То есть "ни... ни" заменяют на "или". А "и... и" — антоним — тоже не надо на "или" заменять (о том, что недавно обсуждали).

Comment: Вот: *В этом предложении можно поставить как двоеточие, так и тире* => и двоеточие можно, и тире можно. *В этом предложении надо поставить как двоеточие, так и тире* => и двоеточие надо, и тире надо, то есть надо два сразу, не подходит по смыслу. Разницу всегда можно в чём-то отобразить.

Comment: А зачем далеко ходить. Вот она разница: *и двоеточие можно, и тире можно* (выбираем); *и двоеточие надо, и тире надо* (выбора нет, нужны оба). Получается, что в первом примере "или" вместо "и... и", а в моём варианте с "надо" — нет. Получилось много набросков, прямо как у Буратино.

Comment: По смыслу можно заменить на: *Здесь возможно двоеточие или тире.* Уже даже слух режет (из-за "или"), а там, конечно, мягче (инфинитив между и прямая связь с ним).

Comment: Сравнить: *Поставьте двоеточие или тире. **Можете** поставить и двоеточие, и тире / как двоеточие, так и тире.* Жесть, как много получилось комментариев. Аж Буратино переплюнул. Где-то час посидел для вас, быстро время пролетело.

Comment: В речи мы бз труда подбираем нужный союз по интуиции в зависимости от ситуации (принцип коммуникативности).  Вот мы поменяли союз, так как изменилась ситуация. А как она изменилась? Вот это надо связать.

Comment: В разговорной речи часто неправильно используют слова. У меня вне ситуаций. Просто показываю разницу и говорю, что не надо использовать "или" вместо других двойных союзов ("ни... ни", "и... и" (*Здесь возможно и двоеточие, и тире*)).

Comment: Разговорная речь заслуживает большего внимания с вашей  стороны:  ведь это наша повседневная речь, в том числе и ваша речь тоже. Вы описываете языковые модели-образцы из грамматики, а нужно уметь правильно ПРИМЕНИТЬ их на практике в каждом случае.  Цитата:  "В разговорной речи часто неправильно используют слова. У меня вне ситуаций".  Вот это НЕВЕРНОЕ утверждение!  Мы именно ПРАВИЛЬНО используем слова. Наш язык точен, выразителен и лаконичен.  Зачем нам частный вариант  ИЛИ…ИЛИ,  если нас вполне устраивает ИЛИ. Здесь язык ушел от формальной логики.

Comment: Заслуживает внимания, но надо понимать, что люди не всегда правильно говорят. Иногда нарушается грамматика, стилистика, даже семантика. Двойное "или" более категорично. *— Будешь мороженое или шоколадку? — Хочу торт. — Или мороженое, или шоколадка.*

Comment: Ладно, Олид,  «мы снова говорим на разных языках…»  Впрочем, мы всегда так говорим, поэтому и не понимаем друг друга. Я говорю о стилях речи (по Ломоносову), а вы  —  о некорректном  разговорном языке. Кстати,  правильная разговорная речь  интуитивна  по своей природе, а ее законы определяюся носителями языка и только потом закрепляются в словарях.  Некорректным же может быть любой стиль,  а чувство языка, как я думаю,   ухудшается у тех, кто очень уж старается соблюдать правила грамматики и логики. К примеру, я говорю о разных ситуациях, вы считаете их одинаковыми, и я не думаю, что вы правы.

Comment: Могу всё объяснить и доказать, но вы ничего не хотите слышать. Не всё, что нормально звучит (интуитивный подход), правильно. Прежде всего вам надо это понять. Вы неправильно думаете. Давайте тогда не соблюдать правила грамматики, чтобы лучше чувствовать язык. Не знаю, какие именно ситуации вы имеете в виду. "Одинаковые" не употреблял, употреблял "похожие".

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, **или** в целом дает одинаковый результат на выходе. Это предложение выбора из одинаковых по сути условий, субъективация выбора, от решения субъекта зависит, в какую сторону качнется чаша весов, находящихся по сути в равновесии.

То есть, если скажем "что ты будешь есть рыбу или мясо?", результат будет примерно одинаковый при обоих исходах, потому что в любом случае без ужина ты не останешься.

А вот **или/или** предполагает один из двух различных сценарных выборов, которые определят дальнейшее развитие событий: ты или будешь учится на врача, или пойдешь в армию.

**Или/или** — взаимоисключающие, ну или как в примере, исключают еще и остальные варианты. Варианты *или/или* могут быть не равнозначными, чаще всего — не равнозначные. Выбор из двух зол меньшего.

А просто **или** остальные варианты не исключает, как не исключает какие-то иные решения.

*Или* — нестрогое условие, *или/или* — строгое.

Насчет надо и можно. *Можно* — это как ложно, предложение, предположение, а *надо* — это уже конкретика: иди и делай.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение!!  Вы даете интересное описание союзов, но не хватает вывода. Мне хотелось бы услышать очень краткое определение различия  двух союзов (понятное любому пользователю языка)  и практическое руководство по их применению  в определенных ситуациях.

Comment: @Sharon всех-всех союзов? И мне не нравится фраза "ваше мнение", и еще мне кажется "спасибо за" - это некорректное употребление слова спасибо.

Comment: Да, а я всегда так говорю. СПАСИБО. I. частица. Выражает благодарность. С. за помощь.  МНЕНИЕ,  1. Суждение, выражающее оценку кого-, чего-л., отношение к кому-, чему-л., взгляд на кого-, что-л.   Мне хотелось бы услышать очень простое объяснение.  Попробуем продолжить"диалог", который я привела в вопросе. Представьте,что любопытный школьник спрашивает у учителя: А почему вы в одном случае использовали союз  ИЛИ, а в другом – ИЛИ...ИЛИ?

Comment: Спасибо, интересная философия, надо подумать.  Но все же мне очень хочется услышать  "школьное" объяснение тоже.

Comment: @Sharon Ну или если школьнику, то или: выбирай мороженое или наггетсы. То есть или - событие еще не произошло, и есть возможность выбора. А или/или - это Аннушка уже разлила масло, чуть до этого момента. Или она разлила или она не разлила, или событие уже случилось или нет. Или одно или другое. Определяющий реальность выбор. А или - не определяющий, потому что выбор или - это иллюзия выбора, просто манипуляция с чувством голода, когда чувство затыкается страстью,  а не что-то серьезное.

Comment: @Sharon от какого слова происходить слово мнение? А то сообщение я удалил, написал другое, в школьных фразах, но не знаю насколько менее путано получилось.

Comment: От "мнить", наверное. Но это уже этимология, прямой связи нет.

Comment: @Sharon этимология > семантики, если семантика не связана с этимологией - то это сленг. То есть говоришь одно, и бессознательное понимает это так, а субъекту кажется что он сказал что-то иное. Можно обмануть другого, но бессознательное обмануть нельзя. А бессознательное рассуждает через связи, в данном случае этимологические и прочие образы. Вот и я думаю что от мнить, а мнить от мания, то есть у меня мания, не обоснованное желание так думать, так считать. Как бы никак не сочетается с рассуждением, потому что рассуждение это некий вывод, на основе чего-то

Comment: @Sharon и далее, "моё мнение" или "ваше мнение". Мнение - это референс на авторитетный источник, либо это вообще не подкрепленное что-то "моё личное мнение"( моё+личное - уже тавтология). То есть "моё мнение" - это какое-то ничем не подкрепленный, никакой аргументацией и рассуждением вывод(? можно ли это вообще назвать выводом), слепая вера что так? Вроде " а я сказал будет так". Эго спросит, а почему ты так считаешь? А ему бессознательное отвечает, замолчи, не твоё дело. Как-то так выглядит внутренний монолог выражающих "своё мнение".

Comment: @Sharon у меня нет мнения, я могу и с вашей точкой зрения согласится, если вы мне дадите непротиворечивую цепочку рассуждений, факты от которых исходите, чтобы стало понятна логика, суть, почему, смысл какой-то. А "моё мнение" - это какая-то мемичная фраза, которую стало модно повторять. Какой смысл в этом, я не понимаю), а фразы, смысл которых я не понимаю, я стараюсь не потерять. Возможно "моё мнение" заменило фразы "моё понимание", я так понимаю. Не знаю, но последняя имеет место быть, а мнение - это какой-то навязываемый сленг, какая-то манипулятивная команда, в моем понимании...

Comment: @Sharon программирующая бессознательное субъекта. Не задавай вопросы, почему ты так думаешь, говорят субъекту, зачем, это просто "твоё мнение", пусть даже это какая-то нелогичная, необоснованная хрень, каждый может иметь "своё мнение" и выражать его. Вам знакомы слова Эго и Бессознательное, кстати?

Comment: "Но это уже этимология, прямой связи нет." - если нет связи с образом, то и слова нет, и далее, в лучшем случае есть термин, в худшем сленг. В этом суть семантики, создать язык без прямых связей с образами, но ярлыками и референсами на другие ярлыки. Чтобы человек говорил и думал что говорит одно, а делал совершенно другое, потому что бессознательное ориентируется по связям образов... или референсам. Да и думает человек, пока не натыкается на нестыковки, и тут, возникает команда стоп " моё мнение" - говорит человек, я его нашел, вот оно, я не понимаю ничего, значит это оно.

Answer (score 2):

В ответе я привожу **очень простое объяснение** учителя для школьника (из заданного диалога).

**Вопрос:**

А почему вы в одном случае использовали союз ИЛИ, а в другом – ИЛИ...ИЛИ?

**Ответ:**

В первом случае используется **более универсальный** (одиночный) союз ИЛИ. Он означает следующее: есть две возможности: тире и двоеточие, так что можно использовать любой из двух знаков. Этой информации **вполне достаточно.**

Но вот ты спросил про **запятую**, то есть обозначил **третий вариант.** Теперь ситуация изменилась.  Запятая сюда не подходит,  и в ответе надо использовать **повторяющийся** союз ИЛИ…ИЛИ.

Это **специальный** союз, он подчеркивает возможность **только** тире или двоеточия. И у него такой подтекст: **«третьего не дано».**

**Примечание**

Грамматический материл по теме можно посмотреть на сайте «Русская корпусная грамматика» в разделе [Сочинительные союзы](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#514).